# Recover ubuntu from shutdown

Tags: recovery-mode

My Ubuntu laptop shutted down while upgrading (`sudo apt-get upgrade`) because of an empty battery. Now when I'm turning my laptop on, screen is empty after log in, right click is not a function. Also I cannot log in with terminal screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) (I'm sure that my login and password are correct).

I can see my screen, files and menus only from recovery mode, in low graphics mode and without network connection. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a bootable Ubuntu CD, than boot from the CD, after chroot your failed system:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys 

sudo chroot /mnt
```

After that issue again the `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` commands. If it fails, than run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`. If finishes, reboot, remove the CD, and try to boot normally. I hope that it helps.

Comment: gives the folowing error:
"mount: mount point /mnt/dev does not exist"
What to do?

Comment: This is because the HDD did not got mounted (first command). Perhaps your HDD is recognized under other name instead of sda1.

Comment: No, first command done successfully.

Comment: Please post the content of `ls /mnt/` command.

Comment: Boot, BOOTNXT, NST, System Volume info, bootmgr, BOOTSECT.BAK, $RECYCLE.BIN

Comment: This was a wubi install? :O

Comment: No dual boot, installed from DVD

Comment: This is funny, your HDD content seems to be some NTFS (with Windows) remains. Let's try to investigate this. After boot, before mount issue this command: `sudo fdisk -l`. This will show you the partitions on your every disk. You have to mount the Linux one.